# How to extract Tensor from Tensorflow Graph without creating a Session?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to modify tensorflow graph object to perform graph level modifications in the framework

**Python Version:** 3.5
**Tensorflow Version:** 0.12rc

**Goal:** Extract tensor from the graph

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.constant(value=0,dtype=tf.float32, name='abcd')
tf.Graph().finalize()
print(tf.import_graph_def(tf.Graph().as_graph_def(), return_elements=[x.name]))
```

The first statement creates an empty graph object and the second statement adds a node into the graph.

The next statement gets the default graph as graph definition and should return the Tensor.

**Expected Result:**

```
Tensor("abcd:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

**Error:**

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5 temp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 450, in import_graph_def
    ret.append(name_to_op[operation_name].outputs[output_index])
KeyError: 'abcd'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/prathyushsp/Git/rztdl/temp.py", line 70, in <module>
    print(tf.import_graph_def(tf.Graph().as_graph_def(), return_elements=[x.name]))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 453, in import_graph_def
    'Requested return_element %r not found in graph_def.' % name)
ValueError: Requested return_element 'abcd:0' not found in graph_def.
```

**Update 1:**

```
sess = tf.Session()
tf.import_graph_def(sess.graph_def, return_elements=[x.name])
```

The above statement gives:

```
[<tf.Tensor 'import/abcd:0' shape=() dtype=float32>]
```

**Update 2:**

```
tf.import_graph_def(tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def(), return_elements=['abcd:0'])[0].name
```

The above statement returns

```
<tf.Tensor 'import/abcd:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=float32>
```

Somehow due to extraction process, the name is changed from **'abcd:0'** to **'import/abcd:0'**. **How to get back the original name?**

Comment: add an argument in your function `import_scope=""` which can remove the prefix

Comment: Added `import_scope=""` parameter in import_graph_def() and got `Error: import_graph_def() got an unexpected keyword argument 'import_scope'` Did you mean to manually remove the prefix? If we need to remove it manually, does it always add `import/` as a prefix?

Comment: Sorry, I just mix it with `tf.train.import_meta_graph`,  the correct argument should be `name=""` for `tf.import_graph_def`